# Is there a way to lookup all reviews of a customer in Amazon's new Product Advertising API?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Using ecs.py, I used to be able to get the reviews of a customer with a query like `ecs.CustomerContentLookup(customerId, ResponseGroup='CustomerReviews')`.

This is now deprecated. Is there an alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at using web page scraping to fetch/get the customer reviews / ratings?

If you know the customer id you should be able to extract all the information you need directly from the Amazon web pages.

Comment: You were asking for an alternative? As Amazon is no longer providing this information, this works!

Comment: agreed, you shouldn't have down voted him, sadly this is probably the only way to do this now